# React.jsをnpm startでブラウザに反映させていたのですが、誤ってcontrol + cをせずにVScodeごと切ってしまいました

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React.jsをnpm startでブラウザに反映させていたのですが、誤ってcontrol + cをせずにVScodeごと切ってしまいました。
その後また別のReact.jsをnpm startしたら写真のようなエラーが発生しどのようにすれば消える（npm start出来る）かわかりません。
`npm cache clean --force` や `rm -r node_modules` の後再度 `npm install`をしたりしましたが消えませんでした。
どなたか解決方法をご存知の方、お力添えいただければと思います。

よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

追記：　 A complete log of this run can be found inの内容はこのようになってます

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.13
3 info using node@v14.17.0
4 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/名前/Desktop/フォルダ名/package.json'
5 verbose cwd /Users/名前/Desktop/フォルダ名/package.json
6 verbose Darwin 19.6.0
7 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
8 verbose node v14.17.0
9 verbose npm  v6.14.13
10 error code ENOENT
11 error syscall open
12 error path /Users/名前/Desktop/フォルダ名/package.json
13 error errno -2
14 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/名前/Desktop/フォルダ名/package.json'
15 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
16 verbose exit [ -2, true ]
```

Comment: エラーメッセージに「詳細なログは以下のファイルをを見てね」とありますが、詳細なログを確認していますか？よろしければ質問に追記もしてみてください

Comment: 「ファイルが見当たらない」というエラーが出ているわけですが、そのファイルのパスがマスクされているようです。どういった状況かを理解するのも困難にしていますが、マスク範囲を見直せますか？（ログファイルの確認とあわせて）

Comment: hinaloe さんが指摘の内容と合わせて、エラーメッセージ等のテキストで表示されたものはなるべく画像ではなくテキストのまま質問に貼り付けてください。情報をマスクする場合も個人情報にあたるような部分などの最小限にとどめてください。

Comment: keitaro_soさん　コメントありがとうございます。先ほど質問内容に追記いたしました。

Comment: hinaloeさん、コメントありがとうございます。マスクされている範囲の内容は /Users/名前/Desktop/フォルダ名/package.json となっております。ただ、package.jsonはしっかり存在しているのですが、、、。

Comment: cubickさん、ご指摘ありがとうございます。まだこの世界に足を入れたてのものでして、このような質問サービスの扱い方にも慣れていないのが正直なところです。ご指導いただいたことを受け止めながら今後も活用していきたいと思います。ありがとうございました。

Comment: npmのバグの可能性もありますが([類似Issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2590))、使用されているnpm v6は当該Issueにもあるようにすでに開発の終了している古いバージョンです。[`npm i -g`など](https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm)を利用して最新のnpmにアップデートしてみるといいかもしれません。